# Is there a way to change the Eclipse plug-in Team Explorer Everywhere login and password?

Tags: eclipse, team-explorer-everywhere

A new developer installed the TEE plug-in into Eclipse.  Because he hadn't yet been granted access, he borrowed my login and username.  Now that he has been granted access, is there a way to go back and change to using his credentials instead of mine?  I couldn't find any way to do it; there doesn't seem to be any option within Eclipse, under Windows->Preferences->Team or anywhere else.

The last resort I can think of is to completely uninstall and reinstall the plug-in, but I'm not even confident that will work in case Eclipse is hanging on to the credentials somehow. And in any case we'd prefer to do it without having to completely reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, TFS workspaces are created *per-user*.  If the new developer were to sign in as himself, he cannot load the TFS workspace that he originally used (impersonating you), and the TFS plug-in for Eclipse will **not** be able to connect his Eclipse projects to TFS.  He'll need to set up a new TFS workspace with the appropriate working folder mappings (the same as the one he's using now).

This can be done manually, but it's probably far easier to simply create a new Eclipse workspace and import the projects again.  There's no need to reinstall Eclipse or the Team Explorer Everywhere plug-in in order to accomplish this, but he *does* need to reconfigure his profiles (the mechanism used to store connection information in Team Explorer Everywhere 2010.)

He should perform the following steps in order to start over (and authenticate as himself):

1. Have the developer shelve or check-in any pending changes.  His pending changes will be lost when he creates a new TFS workspace.
2. Quit all instances of Eclipse.
3. Delete the TEE profile configuration and the workspace cache - the profile configuration has profiles with your authentication, and the workspace cache has a list of your workspaces (with the profile information that is used to connect to them).  The profile configuration file is:

   `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Explorer\10.0\Profiles\profiles.xml`

   The workspace cache file is:

   `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Explorer\10.0\Workspaces\workspaces.xml`
4. Restart Eclipse, and import the necessary projects from TFS.  At this point, he should be prompted to authenticate, and should be able to do so as himself.

**Note:** this mechanism is a bit different in TEE 2012 - we've removed profiles for simplicity.  If you want to authenticate as a different user, we will respect the Windows credentials storage mechanism just like Visual Studio and Internet Explorer.  (Available in Control Panel -> Manage Windows Credentials.)