# Change login credentials to tfs eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs

Yesterday I changed the domain on my computer, and now TFS is complaining about wrong user credentials. I've deleted all the files in the cache folder, tried to change the credentials under Credential Manager in the control panel and so on. How can I decide which user I want to login with to TFS? Very annoying that I can't change the domain and username inside eclipse.

Comment: What version of Team Explorer Everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to be able to change the credentials from within Eclipse, but I don't see that it's possible using Eclipse Juno and Team Explorer Everywhere 2012. (Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091733/667632), it may also matter which version is running on the server side - I think the one I'm using is 2008.)

I got around this limitation be creating a batch file to launch Eclipse under the desired credentials. For example:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\%username% "C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
```

When you run it, it will prompt you for the password. When Eclipse launches, it will be running under the credentials specified on the runas command line.

Comment: Did you try setting credentials in Credential Manager like was suggested in the answer you link to?

Comment: @Edward - Yes, I did try to use the Credential Manager and it didn't work for me. I'm not sure why. I wish it had since it seems like a cleaner solution.

Comment: @DRickard: me too -- I'd love to know why this went wrong, if you'd like to follow up with me offline or at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/tee we'd love to know what happened so we can fix this.