# How do I log out of TFS plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I have added a `TFS` to my `eclipse IDE` on my `Mac`.

I signed into the `TFS server` and everything was fine. I would now like to sign out so that my collegue could sign in.

But there is no clear way to do this!

How do I sign out of my `TFS` account in the `Eclipse TFS plugin` on my `Mac`?

The only thing I could find was the image below in Preferences but there is no entry in the Keychain for TFS

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so actually this is my own question, which I have later found by chance and solved the issue 2 years on

- once eclipse is open click "Connect to a team foundation server"
- once that is loaded click the "Back" button, it will then show you servers you can choose to connect to. click the "Servers" button next to this
- then select the server and click the "clear" button, it will then ask if you would like to clear the credentials, click "yes" then close eclipse and re-open and you are now logged out.

Incredibly un-intuitive

Answer (score 0):

For windows, your may need to delete the accounts and password in the **Windows Credentials**(Control Panel -> Manage Windows Credentials) Here is a similar question for your reference: [Is there a way to change the Eclipse plug-in Team Explorer Everywhere login and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090665/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-eclipse-plug-in-team-explorer-everywhere-login-and)

I'm not so familiar with Mac OS, there must be some settings similar with Windows Credentials. I was wondering if it is  **Keychain Access**.

Answer (score 0):

it uses the credentials from keychain because you checked checkbox to save them at the first place. Simple solution would be to update those credentials from your keychain. You can also just delete them from your keychain so next time you launch eclipse you'll see "sign in to your TFS" link in Team Explorer